# How to connect to MONGODB container with golang web app inside at another container

Tags: mongodb, docker, go, docker-compose

I have a golang web app that use mongodb. I create two containers: one for my_app and the other for mongodb.
I use the official mongo-go-driver/mongo.

```
var client *mongo.Client

//create a mongo.Client
client, err = mongo.NewClient("mongodb://localhost:27017")
//client, err = mongo.NewClient("mongodb://my_first_mongodb:27017")
//client, err = mongo.NewClient("mongodb://:27017")
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("could not create a mongo client:  %v", err)
    panic(err)
}

//connect it to your running MongoDB server
ctx1, cancel1 := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 120*time.Second)
defer cancel1()

//Connect initializes the Client by starting background monitoring goroutines.
err = client.Connect(ctx1)
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("could not connect with mongodb:  %v", err)
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println("trying to start mongodb for my app")
ctx2, cancel2 := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 120*time.Second)
defer cancel2()
err = client.Ping(ctx2, nil)
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("no ping to mongo db could not connect with mongodb:  %v", err)
    panic(err)
}
```

My problem is that I don't know how get(connect) the address ip (localhost) of mongodb inside a container. if I use

```
client, err = mongo.NewClient("mongodb://localhost:27017")
```

doesn't work. but if inside a docker-compose I set the container name (my_first_mongodb) and I use this code:

```
client, err = mongo.NewClient("mongodb://my_first_mongodb:27017")
```

is all fine and it is working.

[image: my docker-compose]

The problem with this solution is that:
Because Docker container names must be unique, you cannot scale a service beyond 1 container if you have specified a custom name. Attempting to do so results in an error  [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#container_name).

Any help please.
Thanks

Comment: Use the service name you are specifying in docker-compose `mongodb`, e.g `mongodb://mongodb:27017`

Comment: Waw you are right. Oren Thank you very much

Comment: Uhm, and you should not scale the `mongodb` service anyway. There is no such thing as automatic replica sets, let alone sharding... And though I appreciate that you are using Fedora and proudly show it, please do not post pictures of your code - post code.

Comment: Here, you have a rather [simplified version of your docker-compose.yml](https://gist.github.com/mwmahlberg/c92936555bfa92191c25cf6972257726)

Comment: Masrkus W Mahlber thanks for your help. I had some struggle to format my code here so i put i picture, my propose was not to show which OS I'm using. Anyway thanks again